# I have tried everything I could find about deleting LibreOffice from my Ubuntu 22.04. Yet it still opens. How can I get it all out?

Tags: apt, libreoffice

I have tried all the apt-get methods I could find online to delete LibreOffice from my Ubuntu 22.04. Most are responding that the system couldn't remove the files because they are already removed. Yet, LibreOffice still opens when I click on a document and the icons are still present in my list of current apps.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491331/edit) to include the complete output of `whereis soffice`.